# What is the proper workflow to model this shape?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I would like to make this shape here in blender with the Subdivision Modifier but I'm not able to make it even with rings.

It is a hard cutted shape along a curved one and I bet it's using Subdivision surface modifier. Here I'm also using a Solidify modifier to make it thicker.

[image: Cutting with rings]

[image: Cutted edge]

Image credits: Nike - [Arezoo from Dibbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/5577478-Nike/attachments/5577478-Nike?mode=media)

Cross-posted from [BlenderArtists](https://blenderartists.org/t/i-want-to-make-this-cutted-shape/1282727)